# Undefined symbols in hello world C++ kernel module

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, g++, kernel-module

I have added C++ support to the Linux kernel version 4.14.41, compiled it and booted using the kernel successfully. I can check the correctness of the C++ module by inserting a `LKM`. This is the module that I am trying to load:

```
#include<c++/begin_include.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<c++/end_include.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("LKM in c++");
MODULE_AUTHOR("MOOL");

class hello
{

public:
        hello();
       void hi();
};
void hello::hi()
{
  printk("Hello world!! \n");
}

hello::hello()
{
        printk("Constructor is being called \n");
        }
 extern "C"
{
   static int __init test_classes_init()
   {
        class hello obj;
        obj.hi();
        printk("Module inserted:\n");
        return 0;
   }
   static void __exit test_classes_fini()
   {
        printk("Module removed:\n");
   }

   module_init(test_classes_init);
   module_exit(test_classes_fini);

}
```

The Makefile:

```
obj-m = helloworld.o
KVERSION=$(shell uname -r)
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

When I enter the make command, the `helloworld.ko` is generated with the warnings

```
WARNING: "begin_fini" [/home/jai/Downloads/helloworld/helloworld.ko] undefined !
WARNING: "end_init" [/home/jai/Downloads/helloworld/helloworld.ko] undefined !
WARNING: "begin_init" [/home/jai/Downloads/helloworld/helloworld.ko] undefined !
```

But when I try to insert it using `insmod helloworld.ko`, the `undefined symbol` error occurs.

**dmesg**:

```
loading out-of-tree module taints kernel
Unknown symbol begin_init (err 0)
Unknown symbol end_init (err 0)
Unknown symbol begin_fini (err 0)
```

These `begin_init`, `end_init` and `begin_fini` are defined in `lib/gcc/crtstuff.c` (which was ported into the kernel). These functions are declared as `extern` in both `crtstuff.c` and `linux/module.h`. This `module.h` is being included in the `helloworld` module above, but still, those symbols become undefined. So, How can I make those functions defined?

Comment: Linux kernel uses its own method for make symbols available to modules. For "normal" symbols `EXPORT_SYMBOL` is used for export a symbol from the kernel. Probably, this will help for compiler stuff too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your kernel C++ implementation is incomplete.  You will have to implement global constructor and destructor support (processing of `.init_array` and `.fini_array` sections properly), or stop using these C++ features in the source code.  This needs cooperation from the kernel module loader.  Changes to the startup code will not work because the startup code is not linked into kernel modules.

Comment: Yes, I had implemented global constructor and destructor support. And I verified it by just writing a sample c++ test program into the kernel source that uses constructors and print messages. I have verified those messages by looking at the `dmesg`. But when I load externally, I am getting the problem.